# Remove gap from HTML table when hiding tbody

Tags: html, html-table

I am trying to hide a portion of my table using `<tbody>` tag but it now shows a gap where the hidden rows are located.

This is the tag I am using:

```
<tbody style='visibility:hidden'>
```

Thank you,

CampSoup1988

Comment: I would have suggested `visibility: collapse;`, but apparently it's not ubiquitous enough, and it's really used to quickly hide columns without recalculating the width of the other columns (as `display: none;` would).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
<tbody style='display: none;'>
```

The reason for this is that `visibility: hidden` hides the element's content, but reserves the space for the element within the `document`. `display: hidden`, however, hides the content and removes it from the document's flow.

It's sort of the difference between 'invisible' and 'not there.'

Comment: *hits head* Sometimes the solution is too obvious!  Thank you for such a quick response!

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

style='display:none'

visibility:hidden will still make the tbody take up space (since its invisible, not undisplayed)

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
<tbody style="display: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
```